# detect if request is from mobile

Tags: c#, web-services, svc

I'm writing a webservice which is call'd from a webpage, I need to know if request comes from web or mobile browser including embeded android webview,
webservice is c# , svc webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the calling User-Agent

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["User-Agent"];
```

And do your check if its mobile or not.

Comment: with regex you mean? it's possible but mabye there is better way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser